# Bringing WFS from Geoserver on top of Openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I am trying to put a WFS layer on top of a openlayer's template I found in openlayers examples. This is the [link](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html) for the untouched version. And [this](https://codepen.io/sanozmen/pen/qxERBB) is the pen I am working on.
I am actually only changing the url defined in function extent and the center of coordinates to be zoomed. I think I do something wrong with getfeature link formation. Or maybe something about the coordinate systems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return 'http://52.42.3.28:8080/geoserver/county/ows?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=county:taxlots&' +
        'outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:4326' +
        'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});


var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-13679410,5217562],
    maxZoom: 21,
    zoom: 14
  })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have switched your extent and GetFeature request to use lat/lon (EPSG:4326) while your map and centre are still in meters(?) probably using EPSG:3857. So your data is drawn just very small and on [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island).

So either switch back to using metres throughout or transform your data to match the map or switch the map to match the data.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the coordinate system accordinlgy. But still, I could not find a way to properly call the WFS layer.